# How do you present your design portfolio / CV so that it gets more reach?

Tags: page-layout, design-principles

I am recently updating my portfolio content to explore new design job positions, but I feel like doing 20+ pages of my work in a .pdf will probably end up not being seen as I have to compete against 500-1000 applicants for the same job.

Did you guys have/had any trick to be recognized by recruiters? The way I know it is not being seen is by placing a hyperlink of a video reel just in the first page of my portfolio which occupies the whole page. From time to time I enter on the video and views do not go up even though "recruiters have seen my CV/portfolio".